# Calculating $\pi$: using a spigot and starting from middle

Tags: pi, python

For interest's sake, I'm writing a Python script that calculates $\pi$ using a spigot method (outlined in detail [here](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/jeremy.gibbons/publications/spigot.pdf)).

However, I'm interested in trying to start from the middle -- maybe I can run multiple scripts simultaneously?  Here's the formula:

```
q,r,t,j = 1,180,60,2

while True:  #infinite loop, on purpose.
    u,y = 3*(3*j+1)*(3*j+2), (q*(27*j-12)+5*r)//(5*t) #// means integer division (truncates)
    yield y #next digit of pi
    q,r,t,j = 10*q*j*(2*j-1), 10*u*(q*(5*j-2)+r-y*t), t*u, j+1
```

I think if I could calculate the value of `q`, `r`, `t`, and `j` at a given spot, I could just input those.  However, I can't think of a way to do that.  Can it be done?

---

Edit: `t` here seems to be `(3n)!/(3!n!)`, and `j` seems to be `n` so far.  Also, `floor(r/t)` seems to be the digits of pi.  Maybe that was obvious, but it seemed cool to me.

Comment: If someone could help out with tags, I'd appreciate it.  Also, I don't know exactly how to put the formula in standard math terms.  If someone wants to help with that, I'd also appreciate it.

Comment: If you could do that, wouldn't you have a formula for the n-th digit of $\pi?$  I'm not sure, since I skimmed the paper only very, very briefly.  I won't say there's no such formula, but I think if you found one, you'd be famous.  Seriously, I think the only way to get the state is to start at the beginning.  You can resume the computation in the middle knowing only those four numbers, but I don't think you'll be able to parallelize it.  BTW, you did notice that this program is only conjecturally correct, right?